# specified destination directory does not exist

Tags: java, exception, hadoop

I am trying to create a Workflow using the Oozie dashboard provided by the Hue interface. Trying to do it step by step, my workflow only has one java step. The relevant piece of code of this java step is as follows:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class InputPathsCalculator {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InputPathsCalculator.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("sout-ing");
    LOGGER.info("putting something in the log");
    JobConf jobConf = new JobConf();
    jobConf.addResource(new Path("/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml"));

    Path outputPath = new Path(args[1]);
    List<Path> inputPaths = calculateInputPaths(args[0], jobConf);
    FileUtil.copy(fileSystem,
                         inputPaths.toArray(new Path[0]),
                         fileSystem,
                         outputPath,
                         false,
                         true,
                         jobConf);
    }
}
```

`calculateInputPaths(...)` is a method that has been tested in isolation and works just fine. The arguments that I pass to the method are a config file, and a `String` with the value `/usr/myUser/outputs/`.

I have two problems here:
1. I can't see anything in any logs. Not what I put into the console, not what I put into the logs
2. The `outputs` directory exists, but I get the following stack trace:

```
org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMainException: java.io.IOException: `/user/eliasg/outputs/output': specified destination directory does not exist
  at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.run(JavaMain.java:58)
  at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:39)
  at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.main(JavaMain.java:36)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:226)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:450)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
  at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: `/user/eliasg/outputs/output': specified destination directory does not exist
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:306)
  at com.ig.hadoop.jsonextractor.InputPathsCalculator.main(InputPathsCalculator.java:37)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaMain.run(JavaMain.java:55)
  ... 15 more
```

I have the feeling that for point 2, my `jobConfig` is missing something that will let it work with hdfs, but I don't know what. About point 1, I am completely lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I was looking at the wrong place. The logs were there, but apparently I needed to look at the map task container logs instead of the list of apps log.
2. I have discovered that adding `hdfs-site.xml` to the `jobConf` is not enough. There is a property that is not enabled by default and needs to be set. That property is:
   `jobConf.set("fs.default.name", String.format("hdfs://%1$s", jobConf.get("dfs.nameservices")));`